# Reverse backward animation doesn't apply properly on mouseout event

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to apply animation on `mouseover` event (works fine) and the same animation with `reverse` and `backwards` properties, to play it back on `mouseleave`. But the second part doesn't work properly. Finally i want the animation plays forward on `mouseover` and backward on `mouseleave`. And if there is a way to apply next animation from that point, where the previous was stopped, please, include it in your answer. Here is my code:

```js
const target = document.getElementById("animated");
target.addEventListener("mouseover", animateForward);
target.addEventListener("mouseout", animateBackward);

function animateForward() {
  target.style.animation = 'custom 1.6s forwards';
}

function animateBackward() {
  target.style.animation = 'custom 1.6s reverse backwards';
}
```

```css
/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes custom {
    25% {
      border-radius: 50% 0 0 0;
    }
    
    50% {
      border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
    }
    
    75% {
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
    }
    
    100% {
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
      background-color: violet;
    }
} 

/* Standard syntax */ 
@keyframes custom {
    25% {
      border-radius: 50% 0 0 0;
    }
    
    50% {
      border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
    }
    
    75% {
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
    }
    
    100% {
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
      background-color: violet;
      
      -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);  
      -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);  
      -o-transform: rotate(180deg);  
      -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); 
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}

div {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="animated"></div>
```

And here is [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fpuvsart/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to play with the `animation-iteration-count` in order to fix this:

```js
const target = document.getElementById("animated");
target.addEventListener("mouseover", animateForward);
target.addEventListener("mouseout", animateBackward);

function animateForward() {
 target.style.animation = '';
  setTimeout(function() {
    target.style.animation = 'custom 1.6s forwards';
    target.style.animationIterationCount = '1';
  }, 0)
}

function animateBackward() {
  target.style.animation = 'custom 1.6s reverse backwards';
  target.style.animationIterationCount = '2';
}
```

```css
/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes custom {
    25% {
      border-radius: 50% 0 0 0;
    }
    
    50% {
      border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
    }
    
    75% {
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
    }
    
    100% {
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
      background-color: violet;
    }
} 

/* Standard syntax */ 
@keyframes custom {
    25% {
      border-radius: 50% 0 0 0;
    }
    
    50% {
      border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
    }
    
    75% {
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
    }
    
    100% {
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
      background-color: violet;
      
      -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);  
      -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);  
      -o-transform: rotate(180deg);  
      -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); 
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}

div {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="animated"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you! But what about this row: *"And if there is a way to apply next animation from that point, where the previous was stopped, please, include it in your answer"*? Do you know how to implement it? It would be really useful to know...

Comment: Can't think of a good solution of the partial-reverse, but I'' think about it :)

Comment: Should i create a new question about it, or it's ok, to stay here?

Comment: Can stay here, I'm not sure it's possible using css (you need to find the relevant key-frame of the current animation and reverse based on that keyframe)

Comment: You can use the `alternate` instead of `reverse` - but it will finish (first) the forwards animation and only then will reverse it.

Comment: Really, i need to play around with animation properties... And as you said, i need to get current keyframe to start the next animation from that point. But isn't there a way to just reverse the animation from point, when the next event happened? I can suggest, that when we will use specific keyframe, it should finish the animation to the end of this keyframe and the next animation will not be really smooth. Isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

For a CSS only solution, leave the `@keyframes`, and use `transitions` instead. When dealing with `:hover`, transitions are almost always what you really need.

E.g, all the properties of your animation can be set independently, and thus they can have their own transition rules.

So your animation could be converted by the following transition, where each keyframe has been replaced by a trio `transition-property`-`transtion-duration`-`transition-delay`.

```css
div {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  /* define all the props */
  transition-property: 
    transform,
    background-color,
    border-top-left-radius,
    border-top-right-radius,
    border-bottom-right-radius,
    border-bottom-left-radius;
 /* set their duration independently */
 transition-duration: 1.6s, 1.6s, 0.4s, 0.4s, 0.4s, 0.4s;
 /* same for delays */
 transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s, 0.4s, 0.8s, 1.2s;
}
div:hover{
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: violet;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
```

```html
<div id="animated"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works perfectly! Does it mean, that we have more control on forward-backward animation when we are using `transitions` instead of `@keyframes`? And when should we use `@keyframes`? Only when we need more complex animations with really different `@keyframes`? (in my case the animation can be replaced by `transition` instead of `@keyframes`, because all keyframes are homogeneous). PS: sorry for my english

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Contrary to transitions, animations are not really meant to be event based like `:hover`. So we've got to take control of them and this means either hard js code, or a lot of keyframes declarations. While transitions are all handled by the browser, so the browser will itslef handle where it is in the animation and how to go back to the next/previous state. This is all a matter of what you are doing. For a repetitive animation, triggered only once at some time (e.g a loading graphic), then animations are a better fit.

Comment: But actually we have less control with transtition, there is no easy way to set the current status of a transition. But we need it less too.